# How can a constant be defined without using a literal?

Tags: java, constants, final, literals

I'm struggling to understand how a constant can be defined without using a literal. Does `final int A = 1 + 1` count?

Comment: What do you mean by "constant"?

Comment: Examples of your question in java please.

Comment: `(3+2)` is a constant too, but not a literal; also it isn't evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Can you give an example of how a constant can be created at runtime, and can you explain what exactly you mean by that?

Comment: @OP If you don't like how people have voted on your question, edit it to improve it, not to vandalize this website.

Comment: You cannot delete a question with an upvoted answer. See [How does deleting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)  Once other people have invested time and effort in a post, you are no longer the sole owner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java Language Specification defines [Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). The first item is "Literals of primitive type and literals of type String", so those literals are also constants. Similarly, it lists "Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables". However, there are many other forms of expression that are composed using only certain operators that are also defined to be constant expressions. See the linked section for the full rules.

Answer (score 1):

A constant is a value that doesn't change:

```
int getRandomNumber() {
    //chosen by a fair dice roll, guaranteed to be random
    return 4; //<- literal
}

public final int random = getRandomNumber(); //<- constant
```

<sub>*[XKCD 221](https://xkcd.com/221/)*</sub>

Here `random` is not a literal, because it is the result of a method call. It is, however, a constant as it is declared `final`.

Java has a limited number of literals:

```
String a = "a"; // string literal
int three = 3; // number literal
int[] manyThree = {3,3,3}; //an array literal consisting of number literals
```

But **any** variable can be a constant by declaring it `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could easily have a non-literal constant. Take this:

```
public class A {
    public static final int A_CONSTANT = new java.util.Random().nextInt();
}
```

`A.A_CONSTANT` is certainly a constant -- it's `final` and `static`, so once that class is loaded, it isn't changing! However, it's not a literal -- it's constant at run-time, not compile-time. Each time `A` is loaded, `A_CONSTANT` has a new, *constant* value, whereas the literal [`4`](https://xkcd.com/221/) is always exactly 4.

Answer (score 0):

A literal is not a constant it is constant. (without  the a)  A constant is a name for a value that can be represented by a literal. (Or by another constant)